# Can't resolve symbol This inspection controls whether the Persistence QL Queries are error-checked

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, intellij-idea, spring-boot

i have some warnings in my intellig-idea. How can i resolve it. i work with spring-boot, so i don't use any xml config files. I just have my application.properties.

here the warning:

```
Can't resolve symbol This inspection controls whether the Persistence QL Queries are error-checked
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary on a line with an error, to the left of a line a sign "bulb", on it you direct - the link on Hibernate QL inspection options, and there among options "**disable inspection**".